# How to send a PHP email via an input form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, outlook

I want to send details from a simple html form to my email without outlook or any email application.

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form>
    
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
             First name:
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type="text" name="first_name">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
             Last name:
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type="text" name="last_name">
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      </form>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks - R.T. Jones

Comment: Check it http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: A Google search for "PHP send email" would be a *great* place to start.